# Why can't I access Apache Drill WebUI on 8047 in Docker using boot2docker in a web browser?

Tags: apache, boot2docker, webui, apache-drill

The ports info returned are null when I inspect the CONTAINER_ID:

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker inspect ccca41b3fe6f | grep -i port “ExposedPorts”: null, “PortSpecs”: null, “PortBindings”: {}, “PublishAllPorts”: false, “PortMapping”: null, “Ports”: {}
```

I cannot access the drill web UI, but sqlline is working fine for default storage plugins e.g., cp. I cannot configure new storage plugins since the Web UI is not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

This has now been fixed by adding a specific route for ip on host and the ip on the docker container :

```
sudo route add net 172.17.0.0/16 192.168.59.103
```